# What kind of rear wheel do I need?

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel

Recently my bike rear wheel was hit by a car at a traffic light. Now it's bent a little and touches the brake. It cannot be fixed by adjusting the spokes and I am going to need a new one. My bike is Schwinn varsity 1200. Here are pics of the wheel.

[image: Here is a picture of the rear bike with cassette]

[image: another pic of the entire wheel]

Comment: You need a 700c road wheel (assuming its a 700c which it looks to be) with a freewheel as it looks like that is a 7 speed.

Comment: Can you tell us how many sprockets in the rear cassette? @Nate Wengert's guess of 7 looks right.

Comment: it has 7 sprockets in the rear casset and 3 in the front one. Schredar valve.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus  would this work https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004YJ2GJ6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1 ?

Comment: If your wheel is only slightly "tacoed" then it can be untacoed with the judicial application of force. Then it can be retrued using the spokes. Unfortunately, aero wheels like yours with minimal spokage don't have much ability to regain true -- and the wheel will never be as strong again. So in the long run, it's best to get a new wheel.

Comment: Based on what little info we have, it would appear that the wheel in your link would work yes. Although that is an odd looking quick release skewer. What does the other side have? A little lever?

Comment: @NateWengert no I have removed the quick release and installed pinheads (locking skewer)

Comment: Ahhhh okay that makes sense. Either way the wheel you linked should be suitable

Comment: @NateWengert I measured the diameter of the rim and it's 25inches. I am confused with all the sizings, the one on amazon at it's 26 inches.

Comment: What do the numbers on your tire say, sizing on wheels is confusing and odd if you look at actual measurements. but there should be a number on the tire in this format xx-xxx such as 23-622 , where 23 is the tire width in mm, and the 622 is the ISO. 622 is the ISO for 700C and 29" wheels. check out this link for more info on that if you would like to learn. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html

Comment: generally you would multiply the 25 you measured by 25.4 which will give you the ISO in millimeters, which in this case would be 635. Leading me to believe it is infact a 700c wheel.

Comment: Yep, find the size markings (there generally will be two different ones) on the TIRE.  One marking will be the ISO size and the other the "traditional" size.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the tire, there should be markings on it that indicate what size wheel it is - generally 700 is a road-bike standard. 26 inch is a mountain-bike standard.

This is a good resource.

http://www.sheldonbrown.com/wheels.html

Also an option is the number of spokes, the more there are, the stronger and more abuse resistant the wheel is generally. Also consider do you have Shimano or another drivetrain- there can be compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to match:

- The basic wheel size -- diameter and (less precisely) width.  (Tire markings give you this info.)
- Brake type -- rim or disk.  (Yours is obviously rim.)
- Axle style -- solid, quick-release, thru axle.  (Yours obviously QR.)  There are also variations in axle diameter, for solid axles.
- Freewheel or freehub.  (I *think* you have a freewheel, but not 100% sure.)
- Number of cogs.  (Looks like you have 7.)
- Overall hub width, measured as the distance between dropouts. (Usually there is only one possibility, given cog count, but there are a few odd cases).

As to number and weight of spokes, that's up to you, as is the degree of "aero" shape of the rim.  These factors don't affect interchangeability.

Comment: For the axle, don't you just need to match through-axle or not-through-axle? It's certainly possible to replace a QR wheel with a tighten-the-bolts-with-a-spanner wheel and vice-versa.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - True, but if it's a solid axle you need to be aware that axle diameter may differ.